# Trying to get property of non-object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have following code

In controller

```
  public function ViewPost($id)
        {
             $viewpost= Post::find($id);
              return view('Guest.viewpost', ['viewpost'=>$viewpost]);
        }
```

In view

```
  @foreach($viewpost as $val)

        <br>
        Post title=
        <a href="viewpost/{{$val->id}}" >{{$val->post_title}}</a>
      <br>
        Post content={{$val->post_content}}
        <br>  <br>
        Featured Image=<img src="{{$val->featured_image}}" height="150" width="150">
      @endforeach
```

But above code throw an error `Trying to get property of non-object.` so i tried following way

```
 $val['post_title'];
```

The above code wont throw an error nor displaying output.

If i print in controller it display output but same in view if i print it give error

```
 print_r($viewpost);
```

I am using `laravel 5.1.` Can any one tell us what i am doing wrong ?

Thank you.

**Update**

after the suggestion of @CodeRomeos.i can able to display data image not loading.

```
<img src="{{$val->featured_image}}" height="150" width="150">

<img src="uploads/penguin.jpg">
```

same works in show view

Comment: Can you post output of print_r($viewpost);

Comment: @GaneshGhalame.now working

Comment: great go ahead !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your controller like this

```
public function ViewPost($id)
{
     $viewpost= Post::find($id)->first();
      return view('Guest.viewpost', ['viewpost'=>$viewpost]);
}
```

or

```
public function ViewPost($id)
{
     $viewpost= Post::find($id)->get();
      return view('Guest.viewpost', ['viewpost'=>$viewpost]);
}
```

Do come back if you still face the issue.!

Comment: thank you.your second answer working .first giving same error .is there any reason because first one should work

Comment: if the record is not found then find() method will return null object and first() method will try to get record from null, that's why it throws exception, but it is not the case in get()

Comment: There should no such error in case you have record of that id. It may be caused by something else. Make sure that the primary key column id in the table is named id only.

Comment: yup i have column id in the table.but now iam facing another problem.can you read my updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88341/discussion-between-coderomeos-and-tester).

Comment: It's giving you an error because you are trying to loop through an object in your view instead of an array. get() will return an array collection where first() will just return an object.